# Small axial inductor for piezo disc buzzer?

Tags: current, inductor, piezo

I'm planning to operate a 15mm piezo disc as a buzzer at about 5 KHz. Can I use a 5mH 0.5W axial inductor for this? Peak current through the inductor is 70 mA, average current 22 mA, average dissipation is 2.3 mW (as per LTspice; with 1 Ohm resistance, I don't know actual resistance of inductor).

[image]

The inductors look something like these...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/we1zc.jpg

update: This is the one I'm considering https://www.ebay.com/itm/50PCS-0410-Color-Ring-Inductance-4-7MH-472K-1-2W-Axial-RF-Choke-Coil-Inductor/351831546222 And a related datasheet https://www.taitroncomponents.com/catalog/Datasheet/TIA0204.pdf lists 85mA max and 20 ohms for the 1mH inductor.

Found another one http://www.mantech.co.za/Datasheets/Products/ECXX_3L.pdf This one says 30 ohms, Isat 120mA, Irms-max 100mA for 4.7mH inductor.

So, I should be safe, right (and can maybe get rid of the additional 20 ohm resistor I have)?

Comment: What is the rated saturation current of the inductor?

Comment: I have no idea... yet. Just made an update to the post.

Comment: Saturation current may be just over 100mA, from what I understand from unrelated datasheets.

Comment: What is the diode for?

Comment: @EdgarBrown I'm getting a negative voltage (<-15V) at the collector if the inductor resistance is low. The diode is also helping me get a nice square wave at the collector. I don't understand why either of those are happening, or their implications.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany As long as I stay within the saturation current and max current limit of the Inductor, I should be OK, right? Is there any chance of the transistor getting fried if the inductor saturates? Can there be an over-voltage condition at the base in that case?

Comment: Yes- okay in the sense the inductor will be doing what it is supposed to be doing. If the inductor saturates there is nothing but resistance limiting the current and the transistor may be damaged from overheating. The base voltage is unlikely to be a factor, unless the transistor breaks down from overvoltage, which is another issue entirely.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks. The resistance should take care of the overvoltage (unless I'm careless). If the inductor breaks down, the Ipeak through collector becomes 140mA, Iaverage is 70mA, and dissipation is 9.6mW. So I guess the mmbt3904 should always be safe (absolute max collector current 200mA).

Comment: @Indraneel I don’t see how that can happen. I would expect +10 or more but not <0. But if that’s the case, you should probably place the diode in parallel with the transistor CE terminals, that would reduce the DC current in the inductor and core saturation issues.

Comment: @EdgarBrown With the diode parallel (ground to collector), the collector voltage rises too much, and the nice square wave becomes a 30uS pulse every time the transistor switches on. All this is in LTspice. I haven't built it yet. Also, I have no real oscilloscope to check all this. [I have a tiny one good for up to 100KHz]

Comment: @Indraneel I assumed you wanted the inductor precisely to have a higher drive voltage. Have you considered adding a capacitor to make it a resonant tank at the desired frequency? 100mA to drive a piezo sounds excessive and inefficient.

Comment: @EdgarBrown Circuit is drawing 22mA average, 65mA peak. That seems to be around what it should be. This is with 30 ohms for the inductor, which seems to be close to the actual value.

Comment: @Indraneel For a piezo at 10V I would expect a current below 5mA average, even below 1mA for a 15mm one. You are more than an order of magnitude above that.

Comment: @EdgarBrown hmm... I will have to check with the small black active buzzer I have. The piezo itself should withstand at least 100V across it. I am keeping it at 35V with my circuit, just below 40V limit of the transistor.